# Using Glide to load image in ImageView of SliderCard gives weird result

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-library, android-glide

I was using [cardslider](https://github.com/Ramotion/cardslider-android) to develop an app, I was grabbing images from web so I use glide to load image in imageview, I've tried in this way

```
public class SliderAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SliderCard> {

private final int count;
private String[] mPlayerImageUrlArray; // Adding an array of Urls instead of int resIds
private final View.OnClickListener listener;

public SliderAdapter(String[] mPlayerImageUrlArray, int count, View.OnClickListener listener) {
    this.mPlayerImageUrlArray = mPlayerImageUrlArray;
    this.count = count;
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public SliderCard onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    final View view = LayoutInflater
            .from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.layout_slider_card, parent, false);

    if (listener != null) {
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                listener.onClick(view);
            }
        });
    }

    return new SliderCard(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(SliderCard holder, int position) {
    holder.setContent(mPlayerImageUrlArray[position]);
}

@Override
public void onViewRecycled(SliderCard holder) {
    holder.clearContent();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return count;
}

}
```

now SliderCard is

```
public class SliderCard extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

private static int viewWidth = 0;
private static int viewHeight = 0;

private final ImageView imageView;


public SliderCard(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);

}

void setContent(final String imgUrl) {
    Log.e("IMG_URL", "setContent() is " + imgUrl);
    if (viewWidth == 0) {
        Log.e("IF", "Called ");
        itemView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                itemView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

                viewWidth = itemView.getWidth()*2;//Here I tried to double the image size but in vain
                viewHeight = itemView.getHeight()*2;//Here I tried to double the image size but in vain
                loadBitmap(imgUrl);
            }
        });
    } else {
        loadBitmap(imgUrl);
    }
}

void clearContent() {
   /* if (task != null) {
        task.cancel(true);
    }*/
}

private void loadBitmap(String imgUrl) {
    //Glide comes in to place here
    imageView.setMaxWidth(viewWidth);
    imageView.setMaxHeight(viewHeight);

    Glide.with(imageView.getContext())
            .load(imgUrl)
            .into(imageView);

}

}
```

but result is

[image: capture]

As you can see the height & width of image is not being perfect as the drawable are, i have made some changes in code as you can see

Question is how can I get Image cover the SliderCard perfectly as Drawables were?

#### UPDATE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_corner_radius"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:alpha="0"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Can you post layout_slider_card.xml

Comment: just a minute ..

Comment: @HamidReza code is added